# Difference between NSLocalizedString and AMLocalizedString

Tags: iphone, localization

What is the difference in using macros NSLocalizedString and AMLocalizedString?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSLocalizedString` is part of the localization solution by Apple. `AMLocalizedString` is a custom localization implementation by [Aggressive Mediocrity](http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.com/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html).

I recommend sticking to `NSLocalizedString` unless you *really* know that you need more features and that they *make sense*. For example, I think that switching the language inside the app at runtime (which the AM solution can do) is a misfeature that is more likely to confuse the user. Imagine you'd have one app in French, another in German, the next in English. Where do you change that? With the usual Apple localization, the user knows how and where to change it: in the iPhone language settings. But then, maybe there is an important and valid use-case for in-app runtime language switching, in which case `NSLocalizedString` won't suffice.